# Change variable at array index, not the actual list

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

Somewhere in my code I have the following:

```
_buttonStates[0] = _upButtonState; _buttonStates[1] = _leftButtonState;
```

is there a way to do this:

```
buttonStates[0] = true;
```

changing the variable _upButtonStates, instead of replacing it with the value 'true'?

I am doing the following:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(_buttons)/sizeof(_buttons[0]); i++){
     if(_buttonStates[i] != digitalRead(_buttons[i])){
        _stateChanged[i] = true;
        _buttonStates[i] = digitalRead(_buttons[i]);
     }
     else{
        _stateChanged[i] = false;
     }
```

But later references to '_upButtonState' end up being outdated.

How do I change the value of a variable in the list instead of overwriting it when accessing it via its index?

Comment: No idea what you're talking about, sorry. At least pick a single language; there is no such thing as "C/C++".

Comment: It sounds like you might be able to do what you want by changing `buttonStates` to an array of pointers. But it's unclear what you want, so I'm not sure.

Comment: The thing stored in `_buttonStates[0]` isn't the variable `_upButtonState` but the value it had at the point of assignment.

Comment: @molbdnilo So I would use pointers to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the literal values in now; you want to store pointers (memory addresses of the variables) in the array instead.
[Example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_array_of_pointers.htm)